# Mesh won't react to light and remains bright

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

I have an issue where some of my meshes won't react to light and just stay bright no matter what I do. I don't know how or when it happened, but I noticed it when opening the file.... This is in cycles render.

Edit: I only recently picked up blender so I'm a complete noob

Here are example screenshots of before and after:

Before

[image]

After

[image]

What could cause this?

Comment: check if you accidently switched your diffuse shader with an emission shader.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I checked and non of the meshes that have got this problem use emission shaders

Comment: can you send a link to your blend file I will take a look at it?

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I already fixed it.

Comment: You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload your .blend file and then post the link into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow managed to enable ambient occlusion in the world properties, disabling it fixed the issue for me